# How to reverse a sequence of CSS transitions and transforms which contain span:nth-child

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

This CSS "animation" in essence consist of several transitions and transforms on span:nth-children which follow each other sequentially using transition delays. It works fine one way, but what is the best way to reverse the animation? Since it is a sequence the solution should reverse the entire sequence. See fiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/6nb0wy68/

```
#Pqb-icon {
  background: white;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
  border-bottom: 20;
  -webkit-transition: .9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .9s ease-in-out;
  transition: .9s ease-in-out;
}

#Pqb-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 12%;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 220, 0.4);
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 36%;
  bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-40px,0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-40px,0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-40px,0px);
  transform: translate(-40px,0px);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease .7s;
  transition: .4s ease .9s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5px;    
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5px;    
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5px;    
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 15%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out .65s;
  transition: .4s ease .8s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 46%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5px; 
  height: 32%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 43%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 5px; 
  height: 32%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 46.5%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-180dreg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg) ;
  -webkit-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -moz-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  -o-transition: .35s ease-in-out .35s;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 51%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 5px; 
  height: 35%;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 51%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
```

Comment: Can't see any animation in that code. Are you mistaking transitions and transforms for animation?

Comment: I see, I edited my question to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only using `transition` and already have the `toggleClass` method, you don't need to change anything in the JS to reverse the transition effect. All that you need to do is add a different transition setting to the default state (not with `class='open'`) like the below snippet.

Essentially what we are doing is this:

- The elements that are causing the effect are the third, fourth, fifth and sixth span elements.
- Initially for the move out effect, the fifth and sixth span elements move out with a delay of .4s.
- The third and fourth span elements move out with a delay of 0.8s (or 0.9s). This has an extra delay because it has to move out after the fifth and sixth are out of the way. The fifth and sixth spans will take 0.4s (transition duration) + 0.4s (transition delay) = 0.8s to complete.
- On toggling the class off, we need this to happen in reverse. That is, the third and fourth span elements should move in to view at a delay of 0.4s while the fifth and sixth span should move in after a delay of 0.8s. So adding the  appropriate `transition` settings to the following selectors would be enough:

  - `#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(3) {transition: .4s ease .4s;}`
  - `#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(4) {transition: .4s ease .4s;}`
  - `#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(5) {transition: .4s ease .9s;}`
  - `#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(6) {transition: .4s ease .9s;}`

**Note:** I have removed the vendor prefixes in the snippet and added the prefix library to keep the code small.

```js
$('#Pqb-icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
```

```css
#Pqb-icon {
  background: white;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;  /*dikte van rondjes*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
  border-bottom: 20;
  transition: .9s ease-in-out;
}
#Pqb-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 12%;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 220, 0.4);
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

/* BEFORE collapsed: hamburger */

#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 12%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  transition: .25s ease;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 36%;
  bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .4s ease .9s;
  transform: translate(-40px, 0px);
  opacity: 0;
}
#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 32%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 43%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 38%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 15%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  transition: .4s ease .9s;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 51%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .4s ease .9s;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 46%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
#Pqb-icon span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 35%;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 51%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  transition: .4s ease .9s;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#Pqb-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
  width: 5px;
  height: 32%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 46.5%;
  background: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  transition: .4s ease .4s;
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <div id="Pqb-icon">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Any suggestions how to keep the P "together" during the transitions (it breaks up in 2 components now...)?

Comment: Do you mean the q and the b (because P doesn't move)? It can be achieved with some tuning, let me check.

Comment: Yes, the q and b I mean.

Comment: @musicformellons: This is going to require quite a lot of rework (like adding extra divs in between). Its a bit more complex than what I felt at first look. I can try that for you but it will take time as I am busy with other work.

Comment: Would be nice! No hurry.

Comment: @musicformellons: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qjnw2wgg/) is a sample fiddle. You can customize it further to suit your needs.

Comment: Great, I will put the pieces together! Thanks a lot!